# Installshield LE Visual Studio 2012 Prerequisites

Tags: visual-studio-2012, prerequisites, installshield-le

When trying to build a deployment package using InstallShield LE project within Visual Studio 2012 how do we specify prerequisites. I see the Requirements section of the Project assistent but it seems this only gives the installer the functionality to go forward with the installation or not based on if certain prerequisites exist. It doesnt seem like it has the functionality to actualy install any of the prerequisites as part of the installation. 
As part of my installation package I am looking to install IIS 7.5 Express and SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP2.

When using Visual Studio 2010 Setup project we have the ability to actualy install the prerequisites as part of the installation package.

On the product page of InstallShield it says the LE version does support:

"Installation Prerequisites
Check for and install prerequisites before your installation is executed."

Am I mising something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look under (2) Specify Application Data | Redistributables. You'll find an extensive list of Setup Prerequisites.

Comment: Thanks Christopher. Now I see how to setup the Redistributables. Unfortunately I dont see IIS 7.5 Express on the list. When looking at the InstallShield documentation I see that we can create our own prerequisites using the InstallShield Prerequisite Editor but based on the InstallShield feature comparison it seems like the Limited edition  doesnt support this and we would have to purchase the professional edition for this

Comment: You could install Professional on a VM for evaluation.  Use the prereq editor to author the PRQ file and then copy it into the machine that has ISLE.  FWIW, I used Linq to XML to create my own PRQ editor but never brought it to market as I'm not sure what to sell it for or how many people would be interested in it.

Answer (score 1):

http://community.flexerasoftware.com/showthread.php?200816-Installing-IIS-as-a-Prerequisite-on-x64-OSs has a method for setting up a new pre-requisite file (.PRQ) that installs WAM and IIS. I've put the code here for posterity:

### PRQ File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SetupPrereq>
    <operatingsystemconditions>
        <operatingsystemcondition MajorVersion="6" MinorVersion="1" PlatformId="2" CSDVersion="" Bits="4" ProductType="1"></operatingsystemcondition>
        <operatingsystemcondition MajorVersion="6" MinorVersion="0" PlatformId="2" CSDVersion="" Bits="4" ProductType="2|3"></operatingsystemcondition>
        <operatingsystemcondition MajorVersion="6" MinorVersion="1" PlatformId="2" CSDVersion="" Bits="4" ProductType="2|3"></operatingsystemcondition>
    </operatingsystemconditions>
    <files>
        <file LocalFile=".\Microsoft IIS\InstallWASandIIS.bat" CheckSum="3205F5B453D8E5FA8795280455BC6B97" FileSize="0,1983"></file>
    </files>
    <execute file="InstallWASandIIS.bat" returncodetoreboot="-1"></execute>
    <properties Id="{9724DBFD-9103-404F-BD53-6B29358C85EF}" Description="This prerequisite installs Windows Process Activation Services (WAS) and Microsoft Internet Information Services (IIS) on Windows 7 x64, Windows Server 2008 x64 and Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 operating systems for MET/TEAM."></properties>
    <behavior Reboot="32"></behavior>
</SetupPrereq>
```

### BAT File

> @echo off cls
>
> @echo. 
>   @echo Windows Process Activation Services (WAS) and Microsoft Internet Information 
>   @echo Services (IIS) must be installed on this computer for it to be able to host
>   @echo the MET/TEAM website. If WAS and IIS are already installed on this computer,
>   @echo this process simply ensures that all necessary components are installed. 
>   @echo.
>   @echo. 
>   @echo Installing Windows Process Activation Services - Please Wait
>   start /w %WINDIR%\sysnative\pkgmgr /l:%TEMP%\InstallWAS.log /iu:IIS-WebServerRole;WAS-WindowsActivationService;WAS-ProcessModel;WAS-NetFxEnvironment;WAS-ConfigurationAPI;
>
> if NOT ERRORLEVEL 0 ( 
>   @echo.
>   @echo An error occurred while installing Windows Process Activation Services -  ERRORLEVEL% 
>   @echo Please refer to the log file %TEMP%\InstallWAS.log
>   @echo for more information.
>   @echo. 
>   pause 
>   EXIT )
>
> @echo. 
>   @echo Installing Microsoft Internet Information Services - Please wait... 
>   start /w %WINDIR%\sysnative\pkgmgr /l:%TEMP%\InstallIIS.log /iu:IIS-WebServerRole;IIS-WebServer;IIS-CommonHttpFeatures;IIS-StaticContent;IIS-DefaultDocument;IIS-DirectoryBrowsing;IIS-HttpErrors;IIS-HttpRedirect;IIS-ApplicationDevelopment;IIS-ASPNET;IIS-NetFxExtensibility;IIS-ISAPIExtensions;IIS-ISAPIFilter;IIS-HealthAndDiagnostics;IIS-HttpLogging;IIS-RequestMonitor;IIS-HttpTracing;IIS-CustomLogging;IIS-Security;IIS-BasicAuthentication;IIS-WindowsAuthentication;IIS-URLAuthorization;IIS-RequestFiltering;IIS-Performance;IIS-HttpCompressionStatic;IIS-WebServerManagementTools;IIS-ManagementConsole;IIS-ManagementScriptingTools;WAS-WindowsActivationService;WAS-ProcessModel;WAS-NetFxEnvironment;WAS-ConfigurationAPI;
>   if NOT ERRORLEVEL 0 ( 
>   @echo.
>   @echo An error occurred while installing
>   Microsoft Internet Information Services - %ERRORLEVEL% 
>   @echo Please refer to the log file %TEMP%\InstallIIS.log
>   @echo for more information. 
>   @echo. 
>   pause 
>   EXIT 
>   )
>
> @echo.
>   @echo Installation was successful! 
>   @echo. 
>   EXIT

Thank you, ACordner, wherever you are now :-)

Comment: n.b. according to [the commentary in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32097688/810632), "pkgmgr" is deprecated and Microsoft suggests using a facility called "DISM" instead.