# How can I create a bootstrapper that requires .Net Framework 4.5?

Tags: .net, frameworks, bootstrapper

I'm using InstallShield 2013 LE and I'm looking to do something similar to [SQL CE 4.0 as a InstallShield Prerequisite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9181157/sql-ce-4-0-as-a-installshield-prerequisite) . Only, I want to install .Net Framework 4.5, if it's not already on the machine. I have the file I need for the framework, but LE doesn't allow me to work on prerequisites.

I saw the recommendation for DotNetInstaller and I downloaded and started working on that. But it looks like DotNetInstaller is very old and doesn't include .Net Framework 4.5 (stand-alone) in its list. Is there a way to add it?

Then I looked at WiX and wasn't sure I could follow the documentation.

I also see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165429.aspx that describes amking bootstrappers directly, but there's very little detail there.

Can anyone point me to a real tutorial for the bootstrapper file? Or, is it possible that someone has the file I'm after and can just post it?

Thanks!!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installshield LE Visual Studio 2012 Prerequisites](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15190024/installshield-le-visual-studio-2012-prerequisites)

Comment: That one tells me how to require IIS, not .Net Framework 4.5.

Comment: It tells you where to click the find the "extensive list".

Comment: Yes, I was at that page originally. I was able to use that section to download the 4.5 distributable and include it with my other files. Setup enforces that the 4.5 be installed, but doesn't install it automatically. Since I'm using LE, the Dependencies section is locked out for me.

Comment: OK, the title of my post should maybe have been _"How can I create a bootstrapper that auto-installs .Net Framework 4.5?"_???

Comment: I reposted it because the title is wrong. It mislead someone who has tagged the question as "maybe has been answered", but if you read the question, it is asking something different.

Comment: How is it possible to update the title and remove the tag that suggests that this is a dup? I looked in the help center, didn't see the question in there. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry about the mix-up. I did end up seeing that I could have changed the title. The new question is at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22994019/how-can-i-create-a-bootstrapper-that-auto-installs-net-framework-4-5 , thanks!!!