# Enabling IIS with Advanced Installer

Tags: iis, iis-7, server, installshield, advanced-installer

I've created install-shield using Advance Installer. One of the features that my install-shield enabling is IIS.

I'm using this shield on customer's servers to check if required software is installed. If the software is not installed install-shield will install it.
IIS is among those software.

I'm not shure how this IIS enabling is working. When no IIS is present on the machine install-shield enables it flawesly. But when it already enabled what happens then? Does install-shield will pass through without any action or it will enable the basic IIS features (features that would be enabled if the IIS were not existed).

I'm afraid to use this install-shield on customer server (where IIS is already installed) because I don't know what it will do. I'm afraid it will disable some IIS features that will affect the current server working state. I don't want to take any chances, I have to know if the install-shield just skips the IIS installation when it already installed or doing something else.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the predefined support to [install Windows Feature Bundles](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/windows-features.html).

Using this support you can easily select which OS feature should be enabled and also set custom conditions. On our YouTube channel you can find examples/tutorials:

- in the following example you see exactly how [IIS is configured for enabling](https://youtu.be/MbGpCXTPCfw?t=136)
- here is also a more generic video, with a [walkthrough over the built-in support from Advanced Installer for enabling Windows Features](https://youtu.be/AgIzPcJeIGI?t=88)

Also, here is [related topic on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32097336/programmatically-enable-install-iis) that might interest you.

Comment: Thank you for the answer @Bogdan Mitrache. YouTube tutorials helped me but I still have a little question. What happens if, for example, my install-shield doesn't need to enable FTP Server but on customer server it already enabled, what will happen then. The install-shield will pass through or will disable it because according to install-shield IIS configuration FTP Server is disabled.

Comment: It does not disable it. It only enables what you selected, anything else gets ignored, remaining as it is configured on that machine. (you can easily test it in a virtual machine)

Comment: also, don't forget to mark the question as answered if it helped you solve the problem.